# How to well design a working mongo query with nested AND & OR

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What's the correct way to create a query in mongodb containing both OR and AND Conditions wrapped inside.
Here's an example of what I tried without success.
Commented according line in code example.

Example:

```
    {
    "$or": [
        {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "type": {
                        "$in": ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"]
                    }
                }, {
                    // Why this condition produces a MongoError
                    "$or": {
                        "_account": "526fcb177675f27140000001",
                        "shared": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "type": {
                        "$in": ["video/mov"]
                    }
                }, {

                    "_account": "526fcb177675f27140000001"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Why this condition produces a MongoError
"$or": {
         "_account": "526fcb177675f27140000001",
         "shared": true
}
```

Because [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) takes an array as parameter:

```
"$or": [
         { "_account": "526fcb177675f27140000001" },
         { "shared": true }
]
```

Comment: Thx. exactly what I was looking for (didn't know that only arrays are accepted)